# Escribir un programa que tenga los valores -2, 5, 8, -9, 10, 15 y –4 y calcule la suma de los elementos positivos y negativos. en c++

Tags: c++

He intentado sumar solo los positivos pero no obtengo el resultado esperado. Aquí esta el código de lo que he intendado en C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[7]={-2,5,8,-9,10,15,-4}; 
    unsigned int n=0;

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
       n+=a[i];
    //cout<<p<<endl;
    }

    cout<<n;
}
```

Comment: Qué te hace pensar que así solo se suman los positivos? Tendrás que ir comprobando en cada vuelta del bucle si el número actual es positivo o negativo

Comment: Recuerda seleecionar cual ha sido la respuesta que más te ha servido @claudio :)

Answer (score 3):

No se sabe exactamente que es lo que pides pero supongo que será esto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int a[7] = {-2,5,8,-9,10,15,-4}; 

  int positivos = 0;
  int negativos = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if(a[i] > 0){
      positivos = positivos + a[i];
    }else if(a[i] < 0){
      negativos = negativos + a[i];
    }
  }
  cout << "Suma de positivos: " <<positivos << endl; //5 + 8 + 10 + 15 = 38
  cout << "Suma de negativos: " <<negativos << endl; //(-2) + (-9) + (-4) = -15

  return 0;
}
```

Recuerda tabular bien para que sea más fácil de entender para los demás :)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del bucle pon un condicional que evalúe si el número es mayor a cero o no. Si cumple la condición, lo sumas.
Con lo que haces, únicamente sumas todos los elementos independientemente de su valor.

Procura indexar bien el código para entenderlo mejor en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca utilicé c++ pero lo que debes hacer es colocar un condicional dentro del ciclo for preguntando si a[i] es > a 0, en el caso de que sea true, se suma y se guarda el resultado en la variable positivos sino pasará a evaluar la siguiente posición del arreglo a. 
Espero haberte ayudado, saludos !!!